# Android app not starting, probably the android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

i want to make my own app, and i just very simply want to start it up. but for some reason i cant make it work on my emulator. I have no error messages so i don't know what is wrong :S Sorry im a novic in programming and i could not find anything that would help me. Thanks !

here are my codes:

```
xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/BBG"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Big Bang Theory" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/HIMYM"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How I Met Your Mother" />

</LinearLayout>
```

android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.watchserie"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>






</application>

</manifest>
```

menu java file:

```
package watchserie.niels;

import com.example.watchserie.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Menu extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't make it work."? What is it doing or not doing?

Comment: Check the name of the layout xml file, and the name of the id which are you passing to setContentView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your package names don't match. You Java file is in the `watchserie.niels` package, while your manifest uses `com.example.watchserie`. As you're using a dot before the Activity name, it instructs that the package name be automatically added to it. Due to this, you're telling Android that your Activity is: `com.example.watchserie.Menu`, while in reality it is `watchserie.niels.Menu`

To fix it, change:

```
package="com.example.watchserie"
```

to

```
package="watchserie.niels"
```

And remove the following line from your Java file:

```
import com.example.watchserie.R;
```

**EDIT** You could change it the other way around too, but Google Play (and other app stores too I guess) will not allow you to upload any app using the `com.example.*` namespace. Because of this, I suggested you choose the package without `com.example` in it.

Comment: @user1330133 I'm glad it did! You can mark this answer as correct by clicking the checkmark under the vote count on the left side, so that this question is marked as solved and doesn't stay in the unanswered tab.